# Firebase app named MyApp already exists (with null checks)

Tags: c#, firebase, asp.net-core

Basically i'm doing null coleasing checks to get an app, and create it if it's not:

```
var firebaseOptionsValue = firebaseOptions.Value; //IOptions<***>

var firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.GetInstance("MyApp") ?? FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions
{
    Credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(firebaseOptionsValue.Json)
}, "MyApp"); //throws System.ArgumentException: FirebaseApp named MyApp already exists.
```

But this still throws an error only once per process lifetime, if any request that service for the first time (service implementation is scoped).

I'm not using firebase default app as all the configuration is passed via environment variables.

I can't get that exception while debugging on my local machine (maybe there is some race condition issues, but both methods are not tasks).